# Where should the user-defined parameters of a framework be ?

Tags: c++, frameworks, evolutionary-algorithm

I am kind of a newbie and I am creating a framework to evolve objects in C++ with an evolutionary algorithm. 
An evolutionary algorithm evolves objects and tests them to get the best solution (for example, evolve the weights neural network and test it on sample data, so that in the end you get a network which has a good accuracy, without having trained it).

My problem is that there are lots of parameters for the algorithm (type of selection/crossover/mutation, probabilities for each of them...) and since it is a framework, the user should be able to easily access and modify them.

*CURRENT SOLUTION*

For now, I created a header file parameters.h of this form:

```
// DON'T CHANGE THESE PARAMETERS
//mutation type
#define FLIP 1
#define ADD_CONNECTION 2
#define RM_CONNECTION 3 

// USER DEFINED
static const int TYPE_OF_MUTATION = FLIP;
```

The user  modifies the static variables TYPE_OF_MUTATION and then my mutation function tests what the value of TYPE_OF_MUTATION is and calls the right mutation function.

This works well, but it has a few drawbacks:

- when I change a parameter in this header and then call "make", no change is taken into account, I have to call "make clean" then "make". From what I saw, it is not a problem in the makefile but it is how building works. Even if it did re-build when I change a parameter, it would mean re-compile the whole project as these parameters are used everywhere; it is definitely not efficient.
- if you want to run the genetic algorithm several times with different parameters, you have to run it a first time then save the results, change the parameters then run it a second time etc.

*OTHER POSSIBILITIES*

I thought about taking these parameters as arguments of the top-level function. The problem is that the function would then take 20 arguments or so, it doesn't seem really readable...

What I mean about the top-level function is that for now, the evolutionary algorithm is run simply by doing this:

```
  PopulationManager myPop; 
  myPop.evolveIt();
```

If I defined the parameters as arguments, we would have something like:

```
  PopulationManager myPop; 
  myPop.evolveIt(20,10,5,FLIP,9,8,2,3,TOURNAMENT,0,23,4);
```

You can see how hellish it may be to always define parameters in the right order !

*CONCLUSION*

The frameworks I know make you build your algorithm yourself from pre-defined functions, but the user shouldn't have to go through all the code to change parameters one by one.

It may be useful to indicate that this framework will be used internally, for a definite set of projects.

Any input about the best way to define these parameters is welcome !

Comment: If you have many parameters, you can wrap them in a struct of some kind and pass that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the options do not change I usually use a struct for this:

```
 enum class MutationType {
  Flip,
  AddConnection,
  RemoveConnection
};

struct Options {
  // Documentation for mutation_type.
  MutationType mutation_type = MutationType::Flip;

  // Documentation for integer option.
  int integer_option = 10;
};
```

And then provide a constructor that takes these options.

```
Options options;
options.mutation_type = MutationType::AddConnection;
PopulationManager population(options);
```

C++11 makes this really easy, because it allows specifying defaults for the options, so a user only needs to set the options that need to be different from the default.

Also note that I used an enum for the options, this ensures that the user can only use correct values.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like the best option, the addition of enum and default values are big advantages over the list of parameters that I used.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of polymorphism.  In your proposed implementation you're doing a switch on constant to decide which polymorphic mutation algorithm you will choose to decide how to mutate the parameter.  In C++, the corresponding mechanisms are templates (static polymorphism) or virtual functions (dynamic polymorphism) to select the appropriate mutating algorithm to apply to the parameter.

The templates way has the advantage that everything is resolvable at compile time and the resulting mutating algorithm could be inlined entirely, depending on the implementation.  What you give up is the ability to dynamically select parameter mutation algorithms at runtime.

The virtual function way has the advantage that you can defer the choice of mutation algorithm until runtime, allowing this to vary based on input from the user or whatnot.  The disadvantage is that the mutation algorithm can no longer be inlined and you pay the cost of a virtual function call (an extra level of indirection) when you mutate the parameter.

If you want to see a real example of how "algorithmic mutation" can work, look at [evolve.cpp](https://github.com/LegalizeAdulthood/iterated-dynamics/blob/master/common/evolve.cpp) in my [Iterated Dynamics](https://github.com/LegalizeAdulthood/iterated-dynamics) repository on github.  This is C code converted to C++ so it is neither using templates nor using virtual functions.  Instead it uses function pointers and a switch-on-constant to select the appropriate code.  However, the idea is the same.

My recommendation would be to see if you can use static polymorphism (templates) first.  From your initial description you were fixing the mutation at compile-time anyway, so you're not giving anything up.

If that was just a prototyping phase and you intended to support switching of mutation algorithms at runtime, then look at virtual functions.  As the other answer recommended, please shun C-style coding like `#define` constants and instead use proper enums.

To solve the "long parameter list smell", the idea of packing all the parameters into a structure is a good one.  You can achieve more readability on top of that by using the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to build up the structure of parameters in a more readable way than just assigning a bunch of values into a struct.  In this [blog post](https://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/description-helpers-for-direct3d-10-10-1-and-11/), I applied the builder pattern to the resource description structures in Direct3D.  That allowed me to more directly express these "bags of data" with reasonable defaults and directly reveal my intent to override or replace default values with special values when necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, however I am not looking for a way to implement the mutation and other operators, I already have an implementation, based on templates since the type of the encoding itself may change. I agree that it is certainly bad practice to start changing the definition of parameters at this stage, I will have many modifications to make to the code. 
I will look at the builder pattern, thank you for the links !